# Intellij IDEA startup error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04

Initellij  IDEA (14) startup error.

```
$ sh idea.sh 
Unrecognized VM option 'ErrorFile=/home/asiri/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Java version

```
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)
```

Env:

Ubuntu 14.04

Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the content of `/home/asiri/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log`? (you could use http://pastebin.com for that)

Comment: I've removed the file thinking it might resolve it. But now there is no file. But still the error remains.

Comment: I'm not sure IntelliJ Idea would work on java 5. Is it possible to try running it on Java 6, or even better Java 8?

Comment: I have a requirement to use java 5. It worked fine earlier. This happened unexpectedly and yet couldn't  find which caused it.

Comment: The version of Java that IntelliJ runs on does not need to be the same as the version that you'll need to use for your project. You can install both Java 5 and 8 and let IntelliJ run on Java 8, and use Java 5 for your project.

Comment: IntelliJ 14 requires at least Java 6 on Linux.

Comment: Yep I'll use java 6 or upper for intellij IDEA and java 5 for the project 
Thanks All !

Answer (score 0):

The JVM option "ErrorFile" got introduced with [Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), so you need to update your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Update to at least jdk 6, otherwise remove that option from the idea.sh file

```
SET COMMON_JVM_ARGS="-XX:ErrorFile=%USERPROFILE%\java_error_in_IDEA_%%p.log" "-Xbootclasspath/a:%IDE_HOME%/lib/boot.jar" -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea14 %IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY%
```

Remove the following part

```
"-XX:ErrorFile=%USERPROFILE%\java_error_in_IDEA_%%p.log"
```